# Getting Not authorize error in whatsapp

Tags: c#, api, whatsapp

```
public void sendMesage()
    {
        string from = "91123456789";
        string to = "9112345789";
        string Message = "Hi";

        WhatsApp wa = new WhatsApp(from, Password, "Aman", false, false);
        wa.OnConnectSuccess += () =>
            {
                lblerror.Text = "Connected to whatsapp....";
                wa.OnLoginSuccess += (phonenumber, data) =>
                    {

                        wa.SendMessage(to, Message);
                        lblerror.Text = "Message Sent....";
                    };
                wa.OnLoginFailed += (data) =>
                    {
                        lblerror.Text = "Login falied...." + data;
                    };
                wa.Login();
            };
        wa.OnConnectFailed += (ex) =>
            {
                lblerror.Text = "Connected to Failed....";
            };
        wa.Connect();
    }
```

I am trying to send message on my mobile through Whats APP Api But getting Not Authorized error.

Please help me out as it is very important for me and today is my demo to client.

Comment: which library are you using

Comment: Which I got from Nuget Package managet.

Comment: There appear to be lots of complaints from people having their accounts blocked for various reasons. Have you tried contacting WhatsApp support?

Comment: No.  Is whatsApp allow us to use WhatsApp API in application...??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Whatsapp.NET/). It is a fork of [this](https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI) and you can see two important things:

First: The project is outdate by almost a year.
Second: This picture presides the main page in the orignal gitHub repository.

[image]

So, I think that the API is deprecated and you are in risk of [being blocked](https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI/issues/1166)

Fina